# Would someone know why my .concat is not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

Would someone know why my code is not working? The console says that “Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined“

```
let tabprenom=[];
let tab=["Rog","Ker","Naal","Sumi","Mat","Poo","Sen","Des"]; 
for(j=0;j<100;j++){
tabprenom[j]="";
}
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){ 
if(i>0){
  tabprenom[j]=tabprenom[j].concat(tab[Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 0)].toLowerCase());
}
else{
  tabprenom[j]=tabprenom[j].concat(tab[Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 0)]); 
}
 document.write(tabprenom[j]+"<br/>");
```

}

Comment: Did you mean to use `i` instead of `j`? After the first loop, `j` is `100`, and `tabprenom[100]` is undefined indeed.

Comment: Lint! Lint! Lint! Debug! Debug! Debug! ...then ask

Comment: No ... The point of the exercice is to create a word which will be formed by three of the "tab"element randomly chosen then I have to put those words in a 100 cases' array

Comment: And where in that array?

Comment: I guess that you have closed your first loop too early?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a misplaced } after the first 1-to-100 `for` loop.

Try this

```
let tabprenom=[];
let tab=["Rog","Ker","Naal","Sumi","Mat","Poo","Sen","Des"];
var j=0;
for(j=0;j<100;j++){
    tabprenom[j]="";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(i>0){
            tabprenom[j]=tabprenom[j].concat(tab[Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 0)].toLowerCase());
        }
        else{
            console.log(tabprenom[j]);
            tabprenom[j]=tabprenom[j].concat(tab[Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 0)]);
        }
        document.write(tabprenom[j]+"<br/>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop closes to early, so you will always retrieve `j=100`